# JSONUtils.isNull returns false. But there is no element inside JSON String

Tags: java, json

I dont know if I use the wrong method?
But when I execute this line of code:

```
JSONUtils.isNull(Score.JSON_SCORE_QUESTION)?null:json.getLong(Score.JSON_SCORE_QUESTION)
```

on that json string(where `Score.JSON_SCORE_QUESTION` is the key "qs"):

```
{"username":"Stefan","points":1295,"level":26,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu","uuid":"08c3a06c-ad9a-4ec0-aec9-4223517389d3","sid":11747,"rank":121,"sstempel":1388768015000,"model":"SCORE"}
```

`isNull` always returns `false`.

Did I need another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSONUtils.isNull](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/util/JSONUtils.html#isNull%28java.lang.Object%29) "tests if the obj is a javaScript `null` (i.e. is `JSONNull`)", but a string (e.g. "qs") is not null in any applicable context. This function is for dealing with *values* and has nothing to do with properties. (Being static, it has no way of using the data in the `json` object anyway!)

Instead, [`JSONObject.has(key)`](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) (or `containsKey`) should be used to determine existance of a property:

```
Long score = json.has(Score.JSON_SCORE_QUESTION)
               ? json.getLong(Score.JSON_SCORE_QUESTION)
               : null; /* or use a long primitive and provide a default */
```

Alternatively, the following *might* work (YMMV):

```
Long score = (Long)json.get(Score.JSON_SCORE_QUESTION);
```